# is this valid C plus valid ebpf, means can I safe the address of any object in long type which is 8 byte size

Tags: c, ebpf, bpf, xdp-bpf

this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
struct mystruct{
int i;
int j;
long k;
long l;
char str[11];

};
int main()
{

    struct mystruct obj;
    obj.i=5;obj.j=55;obj.k=6;obj.k=1000001;obj.l=2000007;memcpy(obj.str,"hello",sizeof("hello"));
    long addr=(long)((uint8_t *)&obj);
    struct mystruct *myobj=(struct mystruct *)(addr);
    printf("%d %d %zu %zu %s\n",myobj->i,myobj->j,myobj->k,myobj->l,myobj->str);
    printf("%zu=%zu\n",sizeof(long),sizeof(myobj));
    return 0;
}
```

So I like to know can I safe the address of any object (struct,union, etc.) or any type variable (int,long,char) into long variable. I showed the the code sizeof struct address or pointer is same as long. Is my above code is OK.

Also does ebpf varifier  allows this?

Also if I have map with value of type long

```
struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
    __type(key, __u32);
    __type(value, long);
    __uint(max_entries, 2);
} hash_map1 SEC(".maps");
```

can I do extract my struct object like following from long type for map value

```
struct hash_elem {
    int cnt;
    struct bpf_spin_lock lock;
};
```

from long type. is this possible in ebpf/xdp?

Comment: You can, of course. And your program will exhibit "Undefined Behaviour" meaning you've deliberately tried to 'break the rules'... Why not try to write code that works instead of trying to write code that doesn't?

Comment: @Fe2O3: This is not a question about the base C language; it is a question about the eBPF verifier. C is **designed** to be extended; the C standard does not specify a walled garden whose walls you break when you go beyond them; it defines an open city with public services in the city but open fields beyond the city center that implementors are welcome to build their own structures in, adding their own definitions to things the C standard leaves undefined, and users of those implementations are welcome to explore those extensions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Are you suggesting that there will be no signed/unsigned problems with putting anything into a "signed long"? No possible truncation or sign extension that will come back to byte? (pardon the pun.) Enjoy the open fields of the wild west... (The eBPF stuff was appended to the OP 1 minute after my original comment.)

Comment: @Fe2O3: Re “Are you suggesting that there will be no signed/unsigned problems with putting anything into a "signed long"?”: No, I am not suggesting that. That is an issue the question is asking about, and one that should be answered in an answer, not dismissed with a snide comment mired in mistaken notions about what undefined behavior is. Re “The eBPF stuff was appended to the OP 1 minute after my original comment.”: No, it was not. The history shows the ebpf tag and “Also does ebpf varifier allows this?” in the original version of the question, eight minutes before your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long addr=(long)((uint8_t *)&obj);
struct mystruct *myobj=(struct mystruct *)(addr);
```

I don't see a reason why the BPF verifier should reject this; you are just casting into and from `long`.

This will be compiled into a 64-bit BPF register anyway and type information will be lost (unless using BTF). The verifier will then infer a type for its own purpose and will correctly recognize this as a pointer to the stack (`PTR_TO_STACK`).

---

> can I do extract my struct object like following from long type for map value

No, that wouldn't make sense. If you store in the map a pointer to the stack, then when your program exists, the pointer may be pointing to invalid memory.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simple:

```
    uintptr_t addr=(uintptr_t)&obj;
    struct mystruct *myobj=(struct mystruct *)(addr);
```

`uintptr_t` type is guaranteed to keep any pointer converted to an integer and it is widely used in the BPF code.